# Sending a request to another site that has a callback that targets my original page

Tags: php, flickr

In my test.php file, I sent a request to a Flickr app I have using

```
header("Location: " . $request);
```

where $request is the URL that I am trying to reach on Flickr.

For my Flickr app, I have to set a callback URL. When Flickr is done with processing my request, it will call the callback URL.

I would like the callback URL to be my original page, test.php.    When I try this, I get stuck in an infinite loop, because test.php is re-sending the request back to Flickr, and Flickr calls my test.php again (repeat ad infinitum until the browser quits).

Is there a way to put some kind of conditional in test.php to check if the request came from Flickr, or at least some way to let the script know that the request has been sent, so don't send it again.

I've already tried it where I changed the callback URL to another page of mine, and that works fine.  I'm just seeing if I could re-use the same page.

Comment: Doesn't Flickr append a GET variable as per section 3 of this page: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html

Comment: It does, but when I try to point tell the Flickr auth API to call back my original test.php, it keep saying "failed to load source for: [URL]" where [URL] is the callback URL I gave it, even though the page is there.  It just keeps going into an infinite loop until the browser cuts it off.  If I set the callback URL to a separate page, I can grab the GET variable via $_GET['frob'].  I was trying to see if I could do all this in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ugly.

The two posted solutions won't work because:

- The referer isnt changed on redirect (well it is cleared if its a http meta redirect, but not if its a header redirect. but it doesnt become something else so easy).
- Putting exiting after a sent header is generally a good idea if there is something else normaly executed afterwards, but its not related to the problem.

Simply put, if it should be the **SAME** page, you need to to store in a file or database or something the redirect counts per ip adress/user and break or something but **NONE** of this is really reliable. You can make it more secure by having a secured token that cannot be reverse engeneered etc but all this doesn't make sense. You could also use cookies. Which is just as unreliable as well.

Regarding your problem, flickr does NOT redirect back to the samep age.
Regarding to their specifications they append ?frob=[frob].
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html

Check for that:

```
    <?php 
if(!isset($_GET["frob"])) {
header("Location: " . $request);
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be if(!isset($_GET["frob"]) as you don't want to re-direct if coming from Flickr....

Comment: yes, of course! i just wanted to see whether somebody notices :)

Answer (score 1):

try checking the `referer` with the `$_server['HTTP_REFERER']`

[Edited]

I just wanted to say that, you should try adding `if condition`

```
// just and example, use some regular expression to check the refere
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != http://flicker.com){ 
header("Location: " . $request);
}else{
 // another code
}
```

Thanks

Comment: referer doesnt change with redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to checking for the (non-)existence of $_GET["frob"], couldn't you set the callback url in Flickr to be `www.mysite.com/test.php?from_flickr=1` and then do

```
if (!$_GET['from_flickr']) {
    header('Location: '.$request);
    exit; 
}
```